# how to replace character in specific columns of data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and I want to clean columns that include the price in character form. I want to remove $ sign and `,` separator and have those columns as numeric.

```
structure(list(Sold.Price = c("", "$177,500", "$180,000", "$180,000", 
"$189,000"), Title.to.Land = c("Freehold Strata", "Freehold Strata", 
"Freehold Strata", "Freehold Strata", "Freehold Strata"), Price = c("$174,900", 
"$177,500", "$180,000", "$180,000", "$189,000"), DOM = c(93L, 
34L, 39L, 56L, 2L), List.Date = c("10/4/2019", "12/12/2019", 
"12/9/2019", "11/12/2019", "1/9/2020"), MaintFee = c("$2,916.00", 
"$373.80", "$331.57", "$320.42", "$1,055.67")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

  Sold.Price   Title.to.Land    Price DOM  List.Date  MaintFee
1            Freehold Strata $174,900  93  10/4/2019 $2,916.00
2   $177,500 Freehold Strata $177,500  34 12/12/2019   $373.80
3   $180,000 Freehold Strata $180,000  39  12/9/2019   $331.57
4   $180,000 Freehold Strata $180,000  56 11/12/2019   $320.42
5   $189,000 Freehold Strata $189,000   2   1/9/2020 $1,055.67
```

I tried this method:

```
combined_csv$Sold.Price <- gsub("\\$", "", combined_csv$Sold.Price)
combined_csv$Sold.Price <- gsub("\\,", "", combined_csv$Sold.Price)
combined_csv$Sold.Price <- as.numeric(combined_csv$Sold.Price)
```

but this doesn't look smart. I want to do all these in one line for all price type columns (Sold.price, Maintfee, etc) . how can I do it?

Comment: Use regex substitution `\\D*`

Comment: @AnilGoyal  you mean, `combined_csv$Sold.Price <- gsub("\\D", "", combined_csv$Sold.Price)` ? but even I do that, I have multiple columns and I should do this one by one for each column. I want to find a way to first list the name of columns I want to change and then make the change at once

Comment: In that case use across with mutate in dplyr

Comment: @AnilGoyal , btw, `\\D*` doesn't work because it removes `.` for numbers such as 33.4 and change it to 334 which is wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(Sold.Price, Price, MaintFee), ~ as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", .x))))

  Sold.Price   Title.to.Land  Price DOM  List.Date MaintFee
1         NA Freehold Strata 174900  93  10/4/2019  2916.00
2     177500 Freehold Strata 177500  34 12/12/2019   373.80
3     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  39  12/9/2019   331.57
4     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  56 11/12/2019   320.42
5     189000 Freehold Strata 189000   2   1/9/2020  1055.67
```

Or in base R we could do:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) {
  if(any(grepl("\\$", x))) {
    as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", x))
  } else {
    x
  }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, the odd things is that this code doesn't work for me and still show the same style as before. I also tried: `a <- a %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Sold.Price, Price, MaintFee), ~gsub("\\$", "", .) %>% as.numeric))` but this doesn't work neither

Comment: Why it does not work? Is there any feature in your original data set that is not present on your sample data?

Comment: @Anoushirvan, no, I used `dput` function to generate my data here, so the exact same data should be used in my workspace. Not sure why it's not returning the correct answer. I am also confused, because the code make sense to me and not sure hwy it's not working for me

Comment: There has to be a reason. It's impossible for the code not to work because nothing specific happens here. Please double check your data or maybe possibly update your `dplyr` (which is very unlikely to cause this error).

Comment: I also believe that something is happening here. Your code seems to be valid and there should be a problem from my side. I

Comment: It's ok just check it and let me know whenever you needed help. Sometimes I myself overlook the very basic/obvious thing. I would be glad to help everyone in particular my compatriots :)

Comment: @Anoushirvan R, as TarJae mentioned below, I just changed `mutate` to `dplyr :: mutate` and it worked! I am surprised because I already loaded `dplyr` using `library` function. Not sure why this happended

Comment: Yeah I think you already attached `plyr` package. Now that I used `plyr::mutate` nothing changes. I also added a base R solution.

Answer (score 4):

We could use `parse_number` (This drops any non-numeric characters before or after the first number) from `readr` package in combination with `across`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(c(Sold.Price, Price, MaintFee), parse_number))
```

```
 Sold.Price   Title.to.Land  Price DOM  List.Date MaintFee
1         NA Freehold Strata 174900  93  10/4/2019  2916.00
2     177500 Freehold Strata 177500  34 12/12/2019   373.80
3     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  39  12/9/2019   331.57
4     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  56 11/12/2019   320.42
5     189000 Freehold Strata 189000   2   1/9/2020  1055.67
```

Comment: Unfortunately, like the solution provided by @Anoushirvan R, this code doesn't work for me and returns the same data frame as the original one. definitely, something is wrong from my side, but not sure what it is. Your solution looks valid to me

Comment: change `mutate` with `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: that's really odd! it worked!! I already loaded dplyr with `library(dplyr)` not sure what's wrong there

Comment: Lol. @Roozbeh_you: typer : `(.packages())` (shows all loaded packages) and I am sure that `plyr` is in the list.

Comment: YES!, `plyr` is the first on the list! what does that mean? does `plyr` make all these issues?

Comment: Here is the explanation.<http://krlmlr.github.io/pdlyr/vignettes/pdlyr.html>

Answer (score 2):

an optional approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(across(contains(c("Price","Fee")),~readr::parse_number(.x)))

  Sold.Price   Title.to.Land  Price DOM  List.Date MaintFee
1         NA Freehold Strata 174900  93  10/4/2019  2916.00
2     177500 Freehold Strata 177500  34 12/12/2019   373.80
3     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  39  12/9/2019   331.57
4     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  56 11/12/2019   320.42
5     189000 Freehold Strata 189000   2   1/9/2020  1055.67
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `currency`

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(where(~ any(str_detect(., fixed("$")))), 
           ~ as.numeric(currency(.))))
```

-output

```
 Sold.Price   Title.to.Land  Price DOM  List.Date MaintFee
1         NA Freehold Strata 174900  93  10/4/2019  2916.00
2     177500 Freehold Strata 177500  34 12/12/2019   373.80
3     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  39  12/9/2019   331.57
4     180000 Freehold Strata 180000  56 11/12/2019   320.42
5     189000 Freehold Strata 189000   2   1/9/2020  1055.67
```